# How to solve Out of Memory Error in android?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I tried to convert byte array into hex string. But i end up in out of Memory error exception.I didn't have any idea about this.

```
        private String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array) {
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : array) {
          int intVal = b & 0xff;
          if (intVal < 0x10)
            hexString.append("0");
          hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal));
        }
        return hexString.toString();
```

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: How big your byte array is? ;) (note: why do you need b & 0xff? a byte can't be more than 0xff)

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment this is my size of image 15980544, bytearray size = 1489960

Comment: @Adriano - this is done to get the signed stuff right

Comment: @user1216003 with that size you cannot do that in memory - can you give some details to your app? what do you do with the string afterwards? If you write to a file you could write the file on the go ..

Comment: @ligi i need to send hex string to web server for uploading the image

Comment: @Adriano When assigning a `byte` to an `int` you need to specify `&0xff` if you don't want it to sign-extend (`byte` is signed in Java). To see why, try the following: `byte b = 255; int i = b; Log.i("foo", "i should be 255, but is "+i);`

Comment: If you really need to convert this to a string, you'll have to write it to a file somewhere. It is way too big. Why are you doing this?

Comment: thanks david.. if you could can you provide me the sample for this.. because i am new... i need to convert image to hexstring and send it to webserver for uploading

Comment: Tnx @DavidWasser! Missed the point :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. You basically want to make the connection to the webserver first and then convert the image into hexstring directly in the output stream so that the bytes go directly to the server and you don't have to first convert the whole image to a gigantic String and then push that to the server.

```
byte[] array; // This is your byte array containing the image
URL url = new URL("http://yourwebserver.com/image-upload-or-whatever");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    // Now you have an output stream that is connected to the webserver that you can
    //  write the content into
    for (byte b : array) {
        // Get the ASCII character for the first and second digits of the byte
        int firstDigit = ((b >> 4) & 0xF) + '0';
        int nextDigit = (b & 0xF) + '0';
        out.write(firstDigit);
        out.write(nextDigit);
    }
    out.flush(); // ensure all data in the stream is sent
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in); // Read any response
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

I've not tried this code, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Thanks for you answer... but the i am posting some other parameters with that.. thats what i am need to convert it..

Comment: You can also post other parameters with it. Just when you get to the place where the image needs to be posted you can do it like this. Otherwise you will find this difficult to do. Your byte array is 1.5MB, when you convert that to hexstring you have a String that is 3MB.

Comment: Ya, but the thing is in server side they has been coded like that it will accept only hex string

Answer (score 0):

don't convert before sending - convert while sending